# Buld DV360 audience creation via API / ReferenceError: "Analytics" is not defined. (line 18, file "Code")

Tags: google-apps-script, google-analytics-api

I am facing an issue ReferenceError: "Analytics" is not defined. (line 18, file "Code") while using the script from this [article](https://www.en.advertisercommunity.com/t5/Advanced-Features/AdWords-Script-Bulk-Remarketing-Audiences-Creation/td-p/643297#)

My goal is to setup remarketing audiences in GA. Overall I have 14 accounts, but the list of audiences will remain the same.

Could you please help me to understand what went wrong?

```
function main() {

var settings = {'linkedView':"60000000",
              'linkedAccountId':"",
              'accountId':'',
              'propertyID':''};

 var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('');
 var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
 var range = sheet.getRange(1, 2, sheet.getLastRow(), 3);
 var values = range.getValues();
 Logger.log(values.length);

 for(var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
 var name = values[i][0];
 var categoryUrl = values[i][1];
 var duration = values[i][2];
 var newAudience = Analytics.Management.RemarketingAudience.insert(
  {
    'name': name,
    'linkedViews': [settings.linkedView],
    'linkedAdAccounts': [{
        'type': 'DBM_LINKS',
        'linkedAccountId': settings.linkedAccountId,
    }],
    'audienceType': 'SIMPLE',
    'audienceDefinition': {
      'includeConditions': {
        'daysToLookBack': 7,
        'segment': 'sessions::condition::ga:pagePath=@' + categoryUrl,
        'membershipDurationDays': duration,
        'isSmartList': false
      }
    }
  },
settings.accountId,
settings.propertyID);

Logger.log(i + ' Audience ' + name + ' has been created');
};
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the Analytics object is not available. It needs to [be enabled](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services) before you can use it.

Here is a basic outline of how to do that:

1. You need to enable the 'Google Analytics API' in the Advanced Google Services menu.
   [[image: Menu Item[1]]
   [image: Popup]
2. Then you need to enable it in the 'Google Cloud Platform API Dashboard' using the link in the bottom of that second picture. Click '+ ENABLE APIS AND SERVICES' > search for 'Google Analytics API' and enable it!

Comment: Thank you very much! I enabled all the necessary APIs, but I am facing another one issue: Invalid value for Integer: (line 18, file "Code")Dismiss. It is the line with the code var newAudience = Analytics.Management.RemarketingAudience.insert. Is there any chance that you might know how to fix it? Thank you!

Comment: @ElenaEpshtein I am only guessing here, but it looks like it is expecting an integer at some point when parsing that object and getting something else. Check `Logger.log(duration);` just before that line. You might need to parse an integar from the string `'membershipDurationDays': parseInt(duration)`.